# Cross Origin Resource Error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to run a page that makes use of ReactJS Library. I am getting the below error:

```
Redirect at origin 'https://fb.me' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:55042' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My code looks like this:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title> Javascript Simple Quiz </title>
  <script type="text/jsx" src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.14.7/dist/react.js" integrity="sha384-xQae1pUPdAKUe0u0KUTNt09zzdwheX4VSUsV8vatqM+t6X7rta01qOzessL808ox" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/jsx" src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@0.14.7/dist/react-dom.js" integrity="sha384-A1t0GCrR06cTHvMjaxeSE8XOiz6j7NvWdmxhN/9z748wEvJTVk13Rr8gMzTUnd8G" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/babel">
    var helloWorld = React.createClass({ render: function() { return
    <div>
      <h1>Hello KEN</h1>
      <p>This is me spittin</p>
    </div>
    } }); React.render(
    <helloWorld />),document.body);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I got rid of the `DOCTYPE` tag intentionally and its not the root of the problem as I don't believe REACT needs it.

Comment: Why `type="text/jsx"` on a JS file?

Comment: I tried that as a last minute solution attempt while trying to explore the problem. You can ignore that. But good catch.

Answer (score 4):

### Quick answer

The problem here is that you are attempting to use [subresource integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) on a resource that is not served with CORS headers.

The short answer is one of

- Make the server support CORS (only possible if you have control of the server)
- Stop doing subresource integrity checking (i.e., remove the `integrity` and `crossorigin` fields from your `<script>` elements)
- Serve the script from a same-origin location (i.e., make the host and domain match between the script location and the page URL)

### What's really going on here?

The `integrity` field of your `<script>` says "Only load this resource if the SHA384 hash of its contents matches this string: `xQae1pUP...`"

However, the same-origin policy requires that a script should know as little as possible about a resource served from another origin. Since your code is not running on the origin `https://fb.me`, it must not learn anything about resources from `https://fb.me` (unless the server at `https://fb.me` actively allows this by [serving an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` CORS header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765/710446)).

However, the subresource integrity mechanism would effectively allow you to inspect the resource with a series of yes/no questions about its contents:

- "Does the resource's hash match `sha384-xQae1pUP...`?"
- "No? Okay, what about `sha384-vPt5Lq1...`?"
- "Not that either, huh? Well, could it be `sha384-18dh2ca...`?"

And so on, until you get the right answer, or at least eliminate a lot of wrong answers.

If the server supports CORS, then the browser will allow your script to read the entire resource anyway, so the browser will certainly also allow your script to determine if the resource's contents hash to a particular value.

Comment: You need to remove the crossorigin field AND the integrity field. This should be accepted as the answer.

Comment: @apsillers I Since you explained what's really going on.. perhaps you could take a look at a similar question i asked here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042123/can-babel-standalone-be-used-if-index-html-is-server-locally-no-webserver

Answer (score 0):

Remove `type="text/jsx"`. Its invalid and the browser isn't seeing it as a remote javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

Using Caddy is a way to avoid cors error in reactjs. Its a web server like Apache, nginx, or lighttpd. It's easy and simple to use [caddy](https://caddyserver.com/docs)