# Can babel-standalone be used if index.html is served locally ? (no webserver)

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

Before i start the question, here is what i already know to avoid answers along the same lines.

**TL;DR:** I already know I can use a webserver and serve the index.html as http://localhost:8081/index.html and it will work.

Now for the question details:

I have created a minimal react-js app, referencing babel-standalone in the index.html file as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Minimal</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='divRootComponent'></div>

    <!-- react reasonably latest for oct/2018 -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

    <!-- babel -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>

    <!-- react CUSTOM component.. i.e. myApp's entry point -->
    <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the index.js contents are:

```
class YoSupComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor () {
    super();

    this.state = {
      message: 'whatever...'
    };
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('YoSupComponent.componentDidMount');
  }

  render () {

    return (
      <div>
        Yo ! Dude or Dudette... sup ?
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const props = {}; //none for now...
ReactDOM.render(<YoSupComponent {...props} />
  , document.getElementById('divRootComponent'))
```

When I tried to access the index.html file in the Browser via file:///path/to/index.html, the error is:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///D:/path/to/index.js' from origin
>   'null' has been blocked by CORS policy:  Cross origin requests are
>   only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https.  @ babel.min.js:24

So thinking the problem is related to the script tags referencing files remotely, I download react and babel locally, and make references local; then again I access file:///path/to/index.html.

Still get the same error ! whats going on? a) why does babel even use XMLHttpRequest (as per the error message) when the babel.js file is now local ? b) why no such message for react files ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type), if you specify a script tag with a type that's not `text/javascript`, it will be ignored by the browser:

> The embedded content is treated as a data block which won't be processed by the browser. Developers must use a valid MIME type that is not a JavaScript MIME type to denote data blocks. The src attribute will be ignored.

In other words, the browser does not load or run `index.js` in your example. This makes sense - if it did, you'd get a syntax error, as your browser can't understand JSX.

What actually happens is that the `babel-standalone` script looks at your HTML, finds all of the script tags marked `text/babel`, *loads them via `XMLHttpRequest`*, and then compiles and runs them.

This is why you're getting CORS errors - the browser's not loading the file, the script is. Unfortunately, I don't think you can resolve this without using a web server or compiling your Babel code ahead of time.

Comment: Many thanks. 2 minutes later i have bought your explanation and accepted the answer is NO babel sux (just kidding) and i cannot use file:/// :-)